# Get capctha image using PHP CURL request and post some data back

Tags: php, curl, captcha

I need to get captcha image, show it on the page, and send some request about that captcha back to the same page.

I tried some code with saving cookies, but that does not work.

```
    // Referer value for login request
    $indexreferer = "https://dichiarazioneprecompilata.agenziaentrate.gov.it/index.htm?v=20190502";
    $captchareferer = "https://telematici.agenziaentrate.gov.it/VerificaCF/VerificaCf.do";

    // Note that __DIR__ can also be used in PHP 5.3+
    $cookieJar = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt';

    // The User-Agent string to send
    $userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5";

    $ch = curl_init('https://telematici.agenziaentrate.gov.it/VerificaCF/VerificaCf.do');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

    // Set header-related options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $indexreferer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieJar);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieJar);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    //getcaptcha($cookies['JSESSIONID']);
    echo $cookieJar;
    getcaptcha();
    function getcaptcha()
    {
        global $cookieJar;
        global $captchareferer;
        global $userAgent;
        // Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://telematici.agenziaentrate.gov.it/VerificaCF/captcha?type=i');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

    // Set header-related options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $captchareferer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieJar);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieJar);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close ($ch);
        file_put_contents('./logo.jpg',$result);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://telematici.agenziaentrate.gov.it/VerificaCF/VerificaCf.do');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "cf=55555&inCaptchaChars=".$_POST['code']."");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');

    // Set header-related options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $captchareferer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieJar);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieJar);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
    }
```

Well, the part about getting an image and showing it works. But the part with sending solved captcha back is not working. I manually solve captcha from my page:

[image]

but it showing that captcha is wrong:

[image]

I know that I am sending that request because I see input code that I am sending beside captcha. I guess the problem is with cookies but I do not know where.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you hit the url https://telematici.agenziaentrate.gov.it/VerificaCF/captcha?type=i you get the new captcha if you try to get captcha image by hitting the above url you will always download the new/different captcha [not the one which was shown in your browser], you need to download the same captcha which is was shown in page during first hit. you can  use  selenium+headless browser for this.

you should use something like selenium to trigger the page and download captcha by injecting js

This is js injection code to get captcha image from webpage

```
var imageElement = document.getElementById("imgCaptcha"); //replace imgCaptcha with original captcha id
var canvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
canvasElement.width = imageElement.naturalWidth; 
canvasElement.height = imageElement.naturalHeight;
canvasElement.getContext('2d').drawImage(imageElement, 0, 0); 
var base64ImageString = canvasElement.toDataURL('image/jpeg').split(',')[1];
```

Send this `base64ImageString` to your service to get it solved.
This  time it wont get changed.